# Proving there are no integer solutions for $y^2=4t+3$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Show that the equation $y^2=4t+3$ has no integer solutions.

Should there be moduar arithmetic involved?

Comment: You could definitely calculate it all $\mod 4$, as you have almost proposed yourself. Look at the possible values for $y^2 \mod 4$.

Comment: yes, 3 is not a square mod 4.

Answer (score 2):

$y$ must be odd, let $y=2k+1$, therefore $y^2=(2k+1)^2=4k^2+4k+1=4(k^2+k)+1=4s+1$, and $1\ne3$.

Comment: Simple, elegant!